# Scala version of Ramda's 'when'

Tags: scala, functional-programming

I often come across situations where I have an object which I'd like to modify only if a certain condition is true. Something like the following:

```
if (condition(object)) return modify(object)
else return object
```

In JS, the Ramda library provides a [when](http://ramdajs.com/docs/#when) function which does exactly this:

```
when(condition)(modify)(object)
```

What I'm failing to find is a neat way of doing this in Scala. Currently I have my own implicit wrapper:

```
implicit class WhenWrapper[T](a: T) {
  def when(condition: T => Boolean)(modify: T => T): T =
    if (condition(a)) modify(a)
    else a
}
```

which allows me to do things like

```
someString.when(_.length > 5)(_.reverse)
```

Is there a similar function built into Scala that accomplishes the same thing?

EDIT (More realistic example):

The if statement works in most contexts, and this question is mildly just out of curiosity. This approach is helpful when writing a bunch of transformers on an object which are chained into a pipeline. We do this regularly with `HTTPRequest`s in Spray.

```
def addAcceptHeaderIfCondition(condition: HTTPRequest => Boolean): RequestTransformer = { r =>
    if (condition(r)) addHeader("Accept", acceptHeaderMediaType)(r)
    else r
}
```

which would be used as part of a pipeline:

```
def pipeline: SendReceive = {
     somePipeline ~>
       addHeaderIfCondition(someToggle) ~>
       morePipeline
}
```

Having to explicitly pass the `r` around just seems unnecessary, something like:

```
def addAcceptHeaderIfCondition(condition: HTTPRequest => Boolean): RequestTransformer = _.when(condition)(addHeader("Accept", acceptHeaderMediaType))
```

just feels neater.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what's the problem with a standard if statement ?
`if(someString.length>5) someString.reverse else someString`

Comment: @C4stor I've added a more in depth example that might explain my motivation.

Comment: So is the issue here that you don't like using the implicit?

Comment: The implicit is fine. My question is whether there's anything built into Scala that accomplishes the same (or similar) thing in this concise way.